# ROSLisp Tutorial Error in add-two-ints

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have what seems to be a completely standard ROSLisp configuration.  I have the talker and listener tutorials working; in fact so does the `add-two-ints-server`, but the `add-two-ints-client` script triggers an error in SBCL:

```
The symbol "ADD-TWO-INTS-CLIENT-MAIN" is not external in the ROSLISP-TUTORIALS-BASICS package.
```

The script looks fine:

```
(ros-load:load-system "roslisp_tutorials_basics" "roslisp-tutorials-basics")
(roslisp-tutorials-basics:add-two-ints-client-main)
```

So I´m guessing that there is a manipulation of the package environment somewhere deep in the ROS libraries that may not work on every system.  These guys on the Web discovered a pretty subtle bug that caused similar behavior.  They said:

> ```
> (DEFVAR *BUILT-IN-PACKAGES*
> ```

```
  (MAPCAN (LAMBDA (PACK)
            (CONS (PACKAGE-NAME PACK) (PACKAGE-NICKNAMES PACK)))
          (LIST-ALL-PACKAGES)))
```

> > You are destructively changing the package-nicknames list of PACK.
> > Don't do that.

> > Changing this to:

> ```
> (defvar *built-in-packages*
> ```

```
  (mapcan (lambda (pack)
            (cons (package-name pack) 
                  (copy-list (package-nicknames pack))))
          (list-all-packages)))
```

> > makes the problem go away.

Is it possible that having quicklisp installed would conflict with ROS?  I´m at SBCL 1.3.1.  Is it advised to upgrade?

-T

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242995/roslisp-tutorial-error-in-add-two-ints/) by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-03**:\

> These guys on the Web

'these guys'?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-03**:
Looking at the responses to other Lisp related questions, I have the feeling that the ROSLisp community isn't very large (any more). It might take some time before you get a reply.

It would be *very* nice if you could report back on any solution/work-around you find. That would help immensely.

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2016-09-07**:
Could you please point at the particular part of the roslisp tutorial from the ROS wiki page when this error happens? I suspect that you are not following the tutorial.

The problem that you encountered is a minor issue, I doubt greatly that it is connected to an SBCL bug.

**Comment by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on 2016-09-07**:
I did another pull of the add-two-ints tutorial and it worked.  By the way, I was not implying that there was a bug in SBCL.  It´s just that I´m really putting the configuration of Lisp through a lot while doing other experiments.  You saved me again.  How do I close this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-07**:
You could accept the answer by @gaya by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That would mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-07**:
We don't typically close questions here on ROS Answers. Marking the question as answered is much more visible from the question list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I committed a fix to the tutorial. Do a `git pull` and try again.
I strongly recommend, though, that you follow the text in the tutorials on the ROS wiki page, e.g. here:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/OverviewVersion#Calling_a_service_interactively

The text in those tutorials will help a lot to figure out what is going on in the tutorial code.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1